# Class member variable loses value after assignment

Tags: typescript, class, oop

I am facing a problem with using classes under Typescript.
I am called two methods on a class instance : "loadNotifTemplates" and "printNotifTemplates". The first one gets data from a MongoDB and stores them in a class instance variable.  The second one prints this variable on the console. Here I get only "[]" on the console giving me the impression that the variable is empty. Here is how my class looks like.
[image]

So line 71 prints OK , but line 76 shows "[]".

Here is how I invoke both methods :
[image]

Why does the "print" function not print data as it has been stored in the variable already?

Looking forward to your replies.

Comment: Please paste code here isntead of images

Answer (score 1):

In OpenPostOffice you are not waiting for the promise returned by `loadNotifTemplates()` to be resolved and hence you are accessing the value `#notification_temples` before it is assigned.

Make this change:

```
await P0.loadNotifTemplates();
```

and then access the value